# How to store a Date in a Spark Dataset without misinterpretation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, timezone, java-time

Java 8 `java.time.LocalDate` allows you to define `Dates` in terms of `Year`, `Month` and `DayOfMonth` without a timezone. It does this by not having a `Long` representation underlying, but instead `Year`, `Month` and `DayOfMonth`. This makes logical sense as when storing a `Date` you don't want it to be interpreted by the viewer to a different date based upon timezone.

`java.sql.Date` however is a "thin wrapper" over a `Long` representation and this is the **only supported Date type** in spark.

My question therefore is, how do you ensure that when you store a `Date` in a Spark Dataset and serialize it to disk (i.e) parquet file that it's read and interpreted as the correct date without passing timezone information?

Example:

I could parse a string `"2016-01-01 02:00"` in England(GMT+0). All I actually want to store is a day/month/year. But as it's a `java.sql.Date` it stores the underlying unixtime at 2AM. I then serialize this and someone on the East coast of America picks it up and boom. It's now `"2016-12-31 21:00"`. If I knew the timezone however I would know that it was actually `"2016-01-01 02:00"`.
If `java.sql.Date` was timezone-less and only used UTC I could understand but it uses `LocalTimeZone` to interpret.

Therefore, how do I store a `DateTime` that can't be mis-interpreted due to `java.sql.Date` storing unix and then using `LocalTimeZone` to interpret the `Date`?

Comment: Spark and dates is a bit of a mess: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.sql.Date` carries no timezone information as you can see from the main constructor signature in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html).

When a timestamp is stored somewhere without timezone information, you need this information to be passed somehow out of band. The safest choice is to store it as UTC time, as the Unix epoch is a long standing convention that can easily be agreed upon for compatibility with many systems.

Since Spark already exposes the facilities to handle `java.sql.Date`s and `java.sql.Timestamp`s I would suggest you stick to those (to also take advantage of the predefined functions in `org.spark.sql.functions`).

Unfortunately there's no way to prevent misinformed clients from deserializing the value with a wrong interpretation. You can pass timezone information as part of a second column, but nothing will prevent a user from just taking the value stored in the first one and assume it's a local date (whatever "local" means in the runtime context).